# Android Studio. SQLite. DATABASE. ImageView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

В БД хранятся имена картинок  с id. По  id  нахожу имя картинки. Все картинки хранятся в папке /AudioArmy/PhotoForDB/, БД и картинки  в одной папке. Как по пути к данной картинке, отобразить её в imageview

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String imagePath = path + "/AudioArmy/PhotoForDB/"+namePhoto+".jpg";
imageView1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String imagePath = path + File.separator + "AudioArmy" + File.separator + "PhotoForDB" + File.separator + namePhoto + ".jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: одна проблема, что  getExternalStorageDirectory()  deprecated in API 29